# create-react-native-app error on yarn start with glob

Tags: react-native

I try to create a React Native app with *create-react-native-app* tool.

The creation of boilerplate app running correctly.

But when I want to start it (*yarn web*) I have an error with "glob" package.
It tell my that glob package is missed.

```
$yarn web
C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.pnp.cjs:21543
      Error.captureStackTrace(firstError);
            ^

Error: @expo/cli tried to access glob, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: glob
Required by: @expo/cli@npm:0.7.3 (via C:\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\)
```

Why create-react-native-app tool do not packaged that library ?

Do I need this package on global or local install ?

Exist another boilerplate tool for create React Native App ?